# Superpositions and expectation values in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, measurement-problem, wavefunction-collapse, superposition

When the wavefunction of a particle is not an eigenfunction of an operator, the property to which the operator corresponds does not have a definite value, Why?
Also consider a linear combination of basis functions:
$$\psi=c_1\psi_1+c_2\psi_2+...=\sum_kc_k\psi_k$$
When the momentum is measured, in a single observation one of the eigenvalues corresponding to the $\psi_k$ that contribute to the superposition will be found, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ hermitian operator corresponding to an observable.

If $\psi$ is an eigenfunction of A, then
$$
A\psi = \lambda\psi
$$
We say: $A$ has the value $\lambda$ on $\psi$.

If it's not an eigenfunction, then
$$
A\psi = \lambda_1\psi_1 + \lambda_2\psi_2+\dots
$$
That is, after the measurement the state changes and you cannot associate a definite value $\lambda$ to it.

Comment: and the second part of the question?

Comment: To a measurement there is always a corresponding basis of orthogonal states. You've written the expansion for the measurement of momenta, I've written the coefficients for some other measurement $A$. It lies at the heart of QM that you can only measure one of these orthogonal states. In your case its $\psi_k$ and the probability to measure it is $|c_k|^2$.

Comment: "...you can only measure one of these orthogonal state..."-is it a fact or can it be explained?

Comment: It's an observation which can be seen as one of the axioms for the construction of quantum mechanics. This is really a thing which QM is built upon and is very fundamental. You should get familiar with this concept!

Answer (score 1):

Consider a system in the state
$$|\psi\rangle=\sum_kc_k|\psi_k\rangle$$
Suppose that this system couples to another system. The coupling will leave unchanged some set S of commuting observables of the original system and will change the others. In general, unless the system happens to be in an eigenstate of that observable this will change the expectation value of the observables that are not in S. So the interaction copies information about the set S but not about other observables.

Now let's suppose that the coupling measures the observable whose eigenvectors are $|\psi_1\rangle,|\psi_2\rangle...$. Before the interaction the state of both systems is
$$|\phi\rangle_{both}(0)=|\psi\rangle|R\rangle=\sum_kc_k|\psi_k\rangle|R\rangle.$$
After the interaction the state is
$$|\phi\rangle_{both}(1)=\sum_kc_k|\psi_k\rangle|R_k\rangle$$
where the R states are the eigenstates of the readout observable. Why does the state $|\psi\rangle$ represent a system in which the relevant observable doesn't have a definite value? In reality before the measurement there is no single fact of the matter about which value you will get when you do the measurement. Rather there will be multiple different versions of the measurement apparatus after the measurement each of which will hold a different value.

Why will you only see one of them? Each version of you will only see one of them because you will not be able to interact with the versions of the measured system with other values. Nor will you be able to interact with the other versions of yourself that see the other values. Before the measurement it is possible for different versions of the system to be measured to undergo quantum interference. The measurement spreads some of information necessary to do this into other systems and the ability to undergo interference can't be restored without undoing the measurements.

See

http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.5082

http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.3245

http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033.